# Php cookie in not SET username

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to create a cookie in PHP for the username.

But Each time I create a cookie, only the password cookie is created
and the username cookie is not created. Only one cookie named PHPSESSID is created.

this is my code:

```
    setcookie("username",'$username',time()+60);
    setcookie("password",'$password',time()+60);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! How do you know that the cookie is not created? Can you show the `Set-Cookie` header from the response? P.S.: Setting the password in a cookie seems like a high security risk

Answer (score 0):

As per document
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_network_setcookie.asp

```
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

You have to change expiry time 60 sec to 600 sec(10 min) or more

```
setcookie("username",$username,time()+600);
setcookie("password",$password,time()+600);
```

After 600 sec it will expired. And not accessible

Comment: OP did not ask why their cookie only lives for 60 seconds though.